# some reason @google @amazon are in my firefox

Tags: firefox

[image: the main page]

For whatever reason this has just recently started to show up on my main firefox browser.

The only thing I can think of it being related too is perl, and some cgi scripts that I've been testing.

Any suggest please? It does seem like an array function but none of my scripts are using that as an array.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Please expand that to an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Those are search shortcuts for Top Sites introduced in Firefox v63.0.

> Added search shortcuts for Top Sites: Amazon and Google appear as Top Sites tiles on the Firefox Home (New Tab) page. When selected these tiles will change focus to the address bar to initiate a search. Currently in US only.
>   ([*source*](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/63.0/releasenotes/#note-787757))

---

<sub>(originally posted as [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100545/some-reason-google-amazon-are-in-my-firefox#comment1813734_1100545) below the question by [@dsstorefile1](https://askubuntu.com/users/799387/dsstorefile1))</sub>

Comment: Search shortcuts for Top Sites in Firefox aka [Speed Dial](https://superuser.com/questions/1322038/)